# how to enable https if application running in tomcat and resources are comming from apache?

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have created spring application, this is running in tomcat and resources(css, images and js) are coming from apache. We are trying to enable ssl but we are not able to get resources from apache. In console getting exception like resources could not be loaded. Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use Apache as a reverse proxy to tomcat. This way, everything will go through Apache. Resources will be served directly, and requests to the appication will be proxied to your tomcat server:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel Scott. I got it.